# PHP URL Shortener: Shortener.php returning an error message

Tags: php, mysql, url

So I am creating a URL Shortener for my site based off of this YouTube tutorial (PHPAcademy) due to a lack of experience in PHP and MySQL, I feel I'm picking it up quickly, however I receive this error message when submitting the URL.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'UPDATE' (T_STRING) in /home/langers/public_html/r/shorten/classes/Shortener.php on line 37

However ,in the code, the line it mentions and the T_STRING 'UPDATE' that implies is unexpected, is needed in the tutorial.

```
<?php
class Shortener {
    protected $db;

    public function __construct() {
        //Demo Purposes
        $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'langers_langers', 'password','langers_website');
    }

    protected function generateCode($num){
        return base_convert($num, 10, 36);
    }

    public function makeCode($url){
        $url = trim($url);

        if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            return '';
        }

        $url = $this->db->escape_string($url);

        //Check if URL already exists
        $exists = $this->db->query("SELECT code FROM links WHERE url ='{$url}'");

        if($exists->num_rows){
            return $exists->fetch_object()->code;
        } else {

        //Insert record without a code
        $insert->$this->db->query("INSERT INTO links (url, created) VALUES ('{$url}', NOW());

        //Generate code based on id
        $code = $this->generateCode($this->db->insert_id);

        //Update Record
        $this->db->query("UPDATE links SET code = '{$code}' WHERE url = '$url'");

        return $code;
        }
    }

    public function getUrl($code){

    }
}

?>
```

Any ideas on how I can fix it so it still updates the MySQL database?

Thanks

Comment: On line 31 you've not closed your quotes.

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens before, when you miss the closing quotes at

```
//Insert record without a code
$insert->$this->db->query("INSERT INTO links (url, created) VALUES ('{$url}', NOW());
```

Please note also that you're using $insert as if it was an object, but it isn't. Perhaps you meant:

```
$insert = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO links (url, created) VALUES ('{$url}', NOW())");
```

Comment: You win this time...i was going to post the same :)

Comment: Thank you, so much! 

I spent so long today and yesterday trying to figure this out!